# waiting for a button to be clickable problem

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Python selenium to scrape excel exports from a set of Splunk dashboards, the problem is that I use WebDriverWait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable to make sure the export button to be clickable after the splunk query search is done, however it gives me timeout error even though the export button is clickable, if I clicked personally on it before it gives the timeout error the code continues flawlessly till it repeats the problem again in a different iteration
this is my code block with the wait function:

```
wd_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
wd_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
```

HTML of the button

```
<a href="#" class="export btn-pill btn-square shared-jobstatus-buttons-exportbutton" data-cid="view29558" data-view="views/shared/jobstatus/buttons/ExportButton" data-original-title="" title="" data-render-time="0"><i class="icon-export"></i><span class="hide-text">Export</span></a>
```

also, sometimes the xpath and css collector fails to fetch the element and I don't know what to do

Comment: Too little information for anybody to offer more rhan guesses which would waste not only your time but also ours.

Comment: @AhmadTarek Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: Please provide the selector you're using and the html of the button in question.